# jQuery check if href is undefined

Tags: jquery

I want to check when an anchor tag has no href value, even though href is present in the tag, and then display a message to the user. eg.

HTML:

**Note - I cannot change the way this anchor tag is defined, so I cannot add href=" ", the html is populated by wordpress and I do not want to change it**

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '') { 
        alert('We do not have more info on this');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

The above code however only works when the href is defined as follows:

```
<a href="" ></a>
```

How do I change my jQuery to check that href exists, but is not defined, like in my html above? I tried the following, but does not work either:

```
if ($(this).attr('href') === undefined) {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Both `undefined` and an empty string is falsy, so all you have to do is check the attribute directly instead of specifically checking for an empty string

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if (! $(this).attr('href') ) {
        alert('We do not have more info on this');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DbgG6/2/)

Comment: This works thank you. But why does the Alert box pop up for all the anchor tags that does not have href defined? Isn't e.preventDefault(); suppose to limit the alert to only the current element?

Comment: Nope, preventDefault prevents the default action, i.e. the navigation from the anchor, it does not prevent anchors without hrefs from being clicked.

Comment: Problem is that I did not click other element. When I click the one element without href, then the alert generates for all the other elements in the DOM without href defined...how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it against `undefine` and `trim` the value and compare against `''`,  Try this:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href === undefined || $.trim(href) === '') {
        alert('We do not have more info on this');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wu24/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use instead as selector:

```
$('a:not([href]), a[href=""]').click(function (e) {
    alert('We do not have more info on this');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```